# How to check if multiple objects in array have the same property value?

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I want to know what is the best approach to check wether two or more objects has the same property value in my case `dueTo`?

My array looks like this

```
Array [
  Object 
    "__typename": "Instalment",
    "_id": "5cd022cf0d805222374197eb",
    "description": "Description",
    "dueTo": "2019-05-16T23:00:00.000Z",
    "instalmentAmount": 200000,
    "paid": false,
  },
  Object {
    "__typename": "Instalment",
    "_id": "5cd022cf0d805222374197ea",
    "description": "Description",
    "dueTo": "2019-05-23T23:00:00.000Z",
    "instalmentAmount": 200000,
    "paid": false,
  },
  Object {
    "__typename": "Instalment",
    "_id": "5cd022cf0d805222374197e9",
    "description": "Description",
    "dueTo": "2019-05-23T23:00:00.000Z",
    "instalmentAmount": 200000,
    "paid": false,
  },
]
```

First I want to know which objects include the value `paid: false`

```
const unpaidInstalments = instalments.filter(
  instalment => !instalment.paid
);
```

Now I want to check if there are instalments in the same day in this case will result to index 1 and 2 and here the question come how do I filter this?

**SOLVED**

Get all the available dates and put them in an object then check if there is more than 1 object which contain the same value and return an array with these objects

```
const sameDayArray = unpaidInstalments.reduce(
  (datesToCheck, instalment) => {
    datesToCheck[instalment.dueTo] =
      (datesToCheck[instalment.dueTo] || 0) + 1;
    return datesToCheck;
  },
  {}
);

const instalmentsSameDay = unpaidInstalments.filter(instalment => {
  return sameDayArray[instalment.dueTo] > 1;
});
```

Comment: what've you tried? even if it's a `O(n^2)` solution?

Comment: I don't get what you want - "in this case will result to index 1 and 2". What do you mean by that? Can you give an example?

Comment: @appleapple `const instalmentsSameDay = unpaidInstalments.filter(
      (instalment, index) =>
        instalment[index].dueTo === instalment[!index].dueTo
    );` but not working

Comment: `!index` is either true or false. What are you tying to do with that?

Comment: did you try two for loop and compare?

Comment: @pbialy by that I mean that the object index 1 and 2 have the same `dueTo` value.

Comment: I think you should pick up a good book or tutorial. do you really understand what `instalment => !instalment.paid` does?

Comment: @appleapple yes it return the objects with value false for paid attribute

Comment: then what you expect `instalment[!index]` to do?